# How to manage the arguments passed to android activities?

Tags: android

I've got a pretty complicated layout: a master-detail view, where the detail fragment contains a pager with 3 other fragments in it. I'm getting a bit lost ensuring that each fragment has the correct arguments passed to it, especially since some data is loaded via async tasks in the main detail fragment and is then pushed into subfragments.

Add to all of this that many fragments are displayed in activities on phones, and I've got lots of different ways of loading the same fragments.

What would be a good way of ensuring that all of the arguments I need are set for each fragment, by every activity/fragment that uses them?

I was thinking of adding a static 'build' method to the fragments that would return an instance of the fragment with the arguments bundle correctly populated, but this doesn't really work when data is set following asyncTasks.

Can anyone suggest how I can manage the data flow between my fragments & activities?

Comment: Basic concept should be an [observer pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html), e.g. implemented by java.util.Observable and Observer

Comment: I'm looking for a tighter interface than an Observer. The problem I've got is that I can't navigate my code very well to see exactly which fragments depend on which others because starting intents or creating fragments sets bundles of arguments instead of clearly defined interfaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking the static 'build' idea one step further, you could create POJOs that hold the necessary arguments for a given fragment and add methods that can do the POJO <-> Intent conversions.

The master view could create a POJO, popuplate its fields, convert POJO to Intent  and pass the intent to the fragments. The fragments then could build their own POJO from the intent.